# Joining 3 Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (CompanyProfile, IndustryTable, MainTable)

**CompanyProfile**

```
CompanyCode      CompanyName      IndustryCode
AAAA             Company A        3
BBBB             Company B        1
CCCC             Company C        4
DDDD             Company D        1
EEEE             Company E        1
GGGG             Company F        2
```

**IndustryTable**

```
IndustryCode     IndustryName     status
1                Manufacturing    ACTIVE
2                Sales            ACTIVE
3                Logistics        ACTIVE
4                Energy           DEACTIVATED
```

**MainTable**

```
CompanyCode  field2
AAAAA        SampleRecord1
AAAAA        SampleRecord2
DDDDD        SampleRecord3
CCCCC        SampleRecord4
EEEEE        SampleRecord5
```

Now I need a Query to Get all the `RecordCount` from **MainTable** Group By `IndustryTable.IndustryCode` (ACTIVE Only), So the above example should give the following output

```
IndustryCode     IndustryName     RecordCount    (Explanation)
1                Manufacturing    2              -Record 3 and 5
2                Sales            0              
3                Logistics        2              -Record 1 and 2
```

Record 4 (CCCCC) will not be show since IndustryTable.IndustryCode 4 is DEACTIVATED

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`select industrycode, industryname, count(*) as total from companyprofile t1 join industry table t2 join maintable t3  where t1.companycode=t3.companycode and t1.industrycode=t2.industrycode and  t2.status="ACTIVE" group by industrycode`

?